# What is the best way to convert an array with NSStrings to NSDecimalNumber?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nsdecimalnumber

I have an `NSArray` with 10 `NSStrings` inside:

```
myArray (
         @"21.32",
         @"658.47", 
         @"87.32"...
        )
```

What's the best way to convert all the `strings` to an `NSDecimalNumber`?

Comment: Did you look at the docs for `NSDecimalNumber`? Do you know how to iterate an array?

Comment: So I have to do it with a for loop?

Comment: There is no other way?

Comment: Yes, you need a loop. How else could it be done?

Comment: That's what I was wondering. Ok thanks!!

Comment: @rmaddy For those who is new to ObjC but has an experience in languages like Python it could be quite surprising that looping through the array is the only way to do it.

Comment: @Avt then they should say something about how they'd do it in another language. This question has almost no info & makes it look like he didn't even give the problem a shot.

Comment: Well, it says to keep you question short and to the point.

Comment: In swift you could use a map statement to do this. The closest thing I can think of to a map statement in Objective-C would using valueForKey on the array, but I don't there is a way in Objective-C to apply an arbitrary block/selector to an array's elements and transform it to a different type of array.

Comment: Of course you could write a function in Swift and call it from your Objective-C if you're against writing a simple for loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple Category on NSArray will allow you to use `map` as seen in other languages

```
@interface NSArray (Functional)

-(NSArray *)map:(id (^) (id element))mapBlock;

@end
```

---

```
@implementation NSArray (Functional)

-(NSArray *)map:(id (^)(id))mapBlock
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [@[] mutableCopy];
    for (id element in self) {
        [array addObject:mapBlock(element)];
    }
    return [array copy];
}


@end
```

---

Now you can use `-map:` in your case like

```
NSArray *array = @[@"21.32",
                   @"658.47",
                   @"87.32"];

array = [array map:^id(NSString *element) {
    return [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:element];
}];
```

---

A NSMutableArray in-place variant could be

---

```
@interface NSMutableArray (Functional)
-(void)map:(id (^) (id element))mapBlock;
@end
```

---

```
@implementation NSMutableArray (Functional)

-(void)map:(id (^)(id))mapBlock
{
    [self enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        self[idx] = mapBlock(obj);
    }];
}

@end
```

---

```
NSMutableArray *array = [@[@"21.32",
                           @"658.47",
                           @"87.32"] mutableCopy];

[array map:^id(NSString *element) {
   return [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:element];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be quite simple with a for loop:

```
myArray (
         @"21.32",
         @"658.47", 
         @"87.32"...
        )

NSMutableArray *numberArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: myArray.count];
for (aString in myArray)
{
  NSDecimalNumber *aNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: aString];
  [numberArray addObject: aNumber];
}
```